# Can I keep the same domain name for a new website to replace the old one on a different platform (wix)?

Tags: dns, domain

I have a question regarding domain names, and I don't find the answer anywhere.

The company I work in has an old website they want to update. We decided to make a new one on Wix, which is much more user-friendly. The problem is my boss would like to keep the same domain name as the old website.

Is it possible to make 301 redirects from the old to the new by using the same domain name? Or is it mandatory to get a different one for the redirects to work? If so, is it better (and possible) to delete the old website and use the old domain name on the new website?

I'm not a programmer in any way, 100% autodidact, so I need more professional expertise than mine for this!

Thanks for your help!

Edit:
In answer to the answer below, we already bought a premium plan. So we can put whichever domain we want.

However, the problem is: we want to keep our domain name to put it on the new website. Therefore, is it a good idea to delete the old website, or is it better to use 301 redirects from our old website to our new one?

I don't know if I'm being very clear, if not please let me know and I'll try to explain differently. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is switch your DNS record from your old provider to Wix.

See [this website](http://www.webhostingsecretrevealed.net/blog/web-hosting-guides/switching-web-host/) for some example instructions. Your instructions will be a little different as you're not backing up your old website and copying it into Wix, you're just backing it up and having a completely new website on Wix. But otherwise the idea is the same.

I'm sure Wix has some support articles about how to do this in their management. Yes, [here's an example](https://www.wix.com/support/html5/article/adding-dns-records-in-your-wix-account), there are probably more.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's really helpful! So basically, after I do this, what happens with the old website? Does it become irrelevant? Will Google find this a problem or do I keep the previous SEO without any issue?

Comment: The old website is effectively not on the internet so it becomes irrelevant. Your www.mycompany.com URL now points at the new website. Google can find it no problem. I have no idea about SEO stuff though.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Wix support](https://www.wix.com/support/html5/article/connecting-a-domain-purchased-elsewhere) you can use your own domain name, but only if you use one of their paid premium services.